# How to bind the hidden property of a component to another component in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, bind

I am wondering how to properly use reference in EXTJS views. More specifically, I would like to bind hidden property of one component to state of other component with given reference. For example, if a view contains a button and a combobox, how to bind hidden property of a button to isSelected state of a combobox.

Here is what I tried, but nothing works:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    viewModel: {},
    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            reference: 'myCombo',
            label: 'Select',
            queryMode: 'local',
            name: 'myComb',
            store: {
                fields: ['value', 'name'],
                    data : [
                    {"value":"1", "name":"Name1"},
                    {"value":"2", "name":"Name2"},
                    {"value":"3", "name":"Name3"},
                    {"value":"4", "name":"Name4"},
                    {"value":"5", "name":"Name5"},
                ]
            },
            editable: false,
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'value',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'myButton',
            bind: {
                //hidden: '{myCombo.getValue()?true:false}'
                //hidden: (!!myCombo.getValue())
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just bind the view model data to combobox value, something like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    viewModel: {
        data: {
            comboboxSelectedValue: '',
        }
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        reference: 'myCombo',
        label: 'Select',
        queryMode: 'local',
        name: 'myComb',
        store: {
            fields: ['value', 'name'],
            data: [{
                "value": "",
                "name": "Unselected"
            }, {
                "value": "1",
                "name": "Name1"
            }, {
                "value": "2",
                "name": "Name2"
            }, {
                "value": "3",
                "name": "Name3"
            }, {
                "value": "4",
                "name": "Name4"
            }, {
                "value": "5",
                "name": "Name5"
            }, ]
        },
        editable: false,
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'value',
        bind: {
            value: '{comboboxSelectedValue}'
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'myButton',
        bind: {
            hidden: '{!comboboxSelectedValue}'
        }
    }]
})
```

Comment: Thank you Arthur, but is there any way that component with given reference could be visible to other components from the same view? I thought the references are for that purpose. Otherwise one can find component by name or itemId. In this example you have bound combobox value, which works, but what if I would like to bind hidden property of button with  isValid property of textfield with email validator?

Comment: You can also use ItemId or query the components and put listener on select event in sibling components.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of that for the above case?